# How to wire an in-celing recessed projection screen

Tags: wiring, ceiling, projector

So, I have a in-ceiling recessed projection screen. This sits flush to the ceiling so all projection screen box lives permanently inside the ceiling.

However, odly, it ships with a 3 prong electrical plug. How do I legally (to confirm to code), wire this up with a romex cable? I would like to keep the 3 prong plug if possible. But if I have no choice, I am OK with splicing the prong off the cable, and making the black/white/ground wire connections to romex wire inside a junctionbox that is secured to the ceiling joist or stud.

The other option is having a somewhat secured 1 gang metal box with a 3 prong electrical outlet that the plug simply connects to. However, I am not sure about the legality of having this setup vs a junctionbox which connects up the romex with the projector screen.

**Option 1: An outlet partially covered inside the ceiling** (projection screen's 3 prong would connect to the outlet box, the metal gang box could then be secured to the joist or stud, a plastic wall plate would also be present and would be screwed to the power outlet -- all of this inside the ceiling).

[image: Option 1]

**Option 2: Use a covered junctionbox secured to a joist or stud**

[image: Option 2: Use a covered junctionbox secured to a joist or stud]

Comment: If a hard wired installation of the equipment is not in accord with the manufacturer's installation requirements, it would be a violation of most electrical codes in the US. It is also worth considering that the operating conditions in a ceiling or attic space may be well outside the operating range of the equipment. Also inadequate airflow and/or surrounding insulation may create conditions that cause overheating, at which point you are relying on a failsafe in the equipment that was not necessarily designed to work in the extreme conditions.

Comment: What do the installation instructions say?

Comment: The connection, whether hardwired or cord-and-plug, must be "*accessible*".

Comment: @Tester101 - this product is described as "in-ceiling" so the entire housing is designed to be placed inside. The installation instructions don't offer any option to connect inside. I would like to do this so that my living room doesn't have an ugly ceiling outlet with the short wire run. As far as "accessible" requirement. How come ceiling lights are allowed in ceiling connections that are hardly accessible. The socket and the bulb housing is accessible but there is a separate metal housing inside the ceiling that is not accessible. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Aman I don't make the codes, I just follow them. If the product is designed to be cord-and-plug connected, then that's how it should be used. If the manufacturer's instructions specify a hardwired option, then by all means follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks again. So I take it then Option 1 is illegal because you can't have 3 prong connection that is not accessible, and option 2 is illegal because if the screen came with a 3 prong connector it would be illegal to modify the connector (by splicing).

Comment: Not "*illegal*", just not code compliant.

Comment: Make the opening larger than the equipment. Use the additional space to access the receptacle. Cover the additional space with a removable panel. @tester101 Violations of the building code are in fact usually illegal. Have been since the days of Hammurabi.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @benrudgers I will do exactly that. If the removable panel is removable via a screw, that will work correct? (i plan to use a 1 gang box that is behind the screen, and is covered by a blank white plate.

Comment: Actually! From one of @Tester101 's other replies, it seems like the junction box has to be accessible without the home owner having to demolish or destroy anything. Being that the projector screen could be considered like a bulb in a bulb fixture (which is removable, via a hex key, or a driver), the junction-box inside the joist will be accessible without having to saw through more drywall. I will now proceed with the original hidden junction-box idea which will remain accessible by dropping the screen out of the ceiling.

Comment: @Aman you should check with your local building department to make sure they feel the same as you, about your idea.

Comment: I called into the manufacturer of my screen and they recommended cutting off the plug and just tying together with electrical tape. Maybe he meant have a junction box as well. I think I'll go with your option 2 as option 1 definitely seems to be not to code. Option 2 seems kind of OK and follows the spirit of the law.